# Missing functionality - is something wrong with the site?

Tags: support, bug

A couple of issues I've noted happening on Politics.SE, but not on other sites in the network:

[This question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/35774/is-hobbes-leviathan-part-of-classical-realism) about Thomas Hobbes and classical realism.  It belongs on Philosophy.SE, not Politics.  But when I vote to close and select "Should be migrated" as the reason, my only choice is Politics.Meta.

A bad answer to [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/35798/why-do-republicans-and-others-accept-the-propagandaic-use-of-the-term-progressi) came up in the Low-Quality Posts review queue, but there were no options to edit, close, or skip, so there was nothing I could do about it from that screen.

I have accounts on several other stacks and don't see this problem on those.  Is there something wrong with the site?

---

Update:

For the second issue, I was able to replicate the voting buttons problem in the review queues on another stack.  I had my browser text size zoomed to 170%, but didn't zoom when I spot-checked other sites.  The buttons disappear off the right side of the screen at >150%. I'd still call this a bug though. The new site layout is a bit less accessibility-friendly than the old layout was.

The first issue remains, however.

Comment: questions regarding bugs are best brought up on meta.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but since political theory questions are on-topic here I'm curious why you felt the need to try to migrate the Hobbes question.

Answer (score 9):

> But when I vote to close and select "Should be migrated" as the reason, my only choice is Politics.Meta.

Stack Exchange's policy is [not to offer predefined migration paths to beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169984/295232). If you're 100% sure the question belongs on Philosophy Stack Exchange, use a custom moderator flag; ♦ moderators can migrate questions to anywhere in the network (provided that the question is less than 60 days old).